# How to disallow these characters € [ \ ] ^ { | } ~ in a java string

Tags: java, regex, utf-8

I need to check if a JAVA string which we send to commzgate(3rd party) as SMS but our SMS fails because our string is containing some invalid/non-readable characters which I need to check first. Basically i need to put a regular expression check in java to validate if my string contains following characters or not :-

€ [ \ ] ^ { | } ~

Any suggestions! Moreover when I try to put these characters in my java file, it does not save and alerts for non-utf8 character message in eclipse, so everytime i have to remove € and save. Is that so my validation is not complete.
Thanks

Comment: [`Java` != `JavaScript`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/245069/1393766), read tags description before you use them.

Comment: A safer thing yet would be to check if the char is valid rather than invalid. In other words check that it is alphabetical or a number or one of the 30 or so symbols you wish to allow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have included an answer in your question - you can use a regular expression to check for these characters and replace/remove them as required. As you are hitting a problem with Eclipse on a non-UTF-8 character (the Euro symbol) you could instead use the unicode character `U+20AC` (which should be it).

[regular expression java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107030/regular-expression-java)

Answer (score 0):

The regexp is `/[€\[\]\{\}\~]/g`
You can do simpler but this one works

For example in js

```
var a = "€[]{}^|~"
var reg = /[€\[\]\{\}\~|^]/g
a.replace(reg, "") //output ""
```

Comment: OP probably didn't mean javascript, you may want to update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use simply:

```
^[^€\\[\\]\\^{|}~\\\]*$
// €  [  ]  ^{|}~  \    < literals
```

Which matches the start and end of string, any characters (or none) provided they aren't in the (escaped) character class. The `^` inside the character class here indicates that it should *not* match.

Note the double-escaped characters because Java requires literal characters to be escaped as well.