# Identify specified text using c#

Tags: java, c#, regex, information-retrieval, information-extraction

Example text : "jhon's email address is jhon@gmail.com"

I got an error when identifying jhon's email address from regex.I'm new for this regex so like to have your valuable answers .Thanks in advance
Expected result : jhon@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EmailRegex](http://emailregex.com/) shares the regex for an email address in multiple programming languages. Here are two examples:

Java:

```
/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i
```

C#:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

To use the regex, look at the [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation or an [Java example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107030/regular-expression-java) / [C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740984/c-sharp-regex-matches-example)

Comment: Yes .Thats for the validation purpose...so how can i grab email with using above expression tags

Comment: Look at the linked examples how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your email is separated by white spaces and has '@' in the middle

```
    public static void Main()
{
    string text = "There is an email@email.com address in this string";
    int indexOfAt = text.IndexOf('@');
    int end = text.IndexOf(' ', indexOfAt);
    int start = text.LastIndexOf(' ', indexOfAt)+1;
    string email = text.Substring(start, end - start);
    Console.WriteLine(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you would use something like this to find all of the email addresses in a given piece of text:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class EmailAddressMatcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "jhon's email address is jhon@gmail.com";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to capture the matched email addresses, simply do that in the `while (matcher.find())` loop.  Each `matcher.group(1)` is an email address found in the text.